# What does "big as ostriches, twice as ornery" mean?

Tags: idioms

Here are passages from the movie "[Leave Her to Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leave_Her_to_Heaven)", 1945.

> Ellen, we've got plenty of wild turkey this year.
>   Wonderful.
>   Big as ostriches, twice as ornery.

I wonder what "twice as [ornery]" means.

Comment: What did the dictionary tell you about ornery?

Comment: @StoneyB Bad-tempered or difficult to deal with:

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ornery

Comment: Then your problem is with "twice"? or "twice as"?

Comment: @StoneyB I thought it's an idiom. No?

Comment: It's only an "idiom" insofar as we often say *X is **twice as good** as Y* when we don't really know or care *exactly* how much better X is. In exactly the same context, with effectively exactly the same meaning, someone might say *X is **a million times better** than Y*, but idiomatically no-one says, for example, *X is **six** times as good as Y* unless there's some accepted measurable quality involved that clearly suggests exactly a six-fold improvement (not a five-fold or seven-fold improvement).

Comment: This question would be twice as good if it didn't irrelevantly introduce the relatively unusual/slangy adjective ***ornery*** - which has nothing to do with the basic *twice as [adjective]* construction, and the meaning of which OP already knows.

Comment: @MakotoKato "Large as life and twice as natural" was a 19th century catchphrase that's gone through countless variations. It doesn't have any particular meaning beyond what it actually says: think of it as a template for a mild joke rather than as an idiom.

Answer (score 4):

Ornery means *bad-tempered or difficult to deal with*.

So *twice as ornery* would mean that the wild turkey is twice as bad-tempered as an ostrich.

As mentioned above, *twice as* doesn't literally mean two times as much. It is being used idiomatically to mean *significantly more than*.

Comment: @MakotoKato It's a mild joke: one of the things that is "wonderful" about wild turkey.